# Play 2.6 Messages Migration

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm currently trying to migrate a project from Play 2.5 to Play 2.6 and have read this [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/MessagesMigration26) to migrate the messages API. I'm still getting the error:

```
An implicit Messages instance was not found.
```

When trying to create a custom error handler like this:

```
class ErrorHandler @Inject()(
  env: Environment,
  conf: Configuration,
  sourceMapper: OptionalSourceMapper,
  router: Provider[Router],
  override val messagesApi: MessagesApi
) extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler(env, conf, sourceMapper, router) with I18nSupport {

  // ...

}
```

Comment: Post the code section where the error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The trait `I18nSupport` will be able to provide a `Messages` instance. But for this it needs to have an `implicit request` in its scope:

```
implicit def request2Messages(implicit request: RequestHeader): Messages
```

Make sure you have an marked your request as `implicit`